# What's the equivalent in C# of this VB code on an Outlook form?

Tags: c#, vba, outlook-addin

Basically, how do I link an Outlook form and a C# back end? In VB you can write on the form

```
Sub ButtonName_Click()
    Dim Recipients

    With Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Message")
        Set Recipients = .Controls("To")
    End With
End Sub
```

which will fire whenever the button named "ButtonName" on the form is clicked and will set the variable *Recipients* to a string of whatever is in the `To` text box.

Now I have a custom form, and I have a VS C# Outlook Add-in, and they're two separate things. I've got an event handler that can catch `MailItem` objects, but I don't know how to handle custom form button clicks or even how to access elements on the form.

EDIT - <strike>Just to clarify, the custom form was created in Outlook and then its .ofs was imported into VS. Both Outlook and VS are 2010.</strike> I have since redesigned the form in VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Double-click on the button `Name` on the form. This will generate a handler for the default event which happens to be "click" in this case. It will generate a method named `buttonName_Click`.
2. Declare `recipients` in your class of type `string`: `private string recipients`.
3. In `buttonName_Click` assign to `recipients` as appropriate.

In order to know exactly what code to write in the handler, I'll need to know what type of add-in this is. Most likely, the C# code will look something like:

```
recipients = this.Item.GetInspector().ModifiedFormPages["Message"].Controls["To"];
```

Comment: The form was designed in Outlook and then the .ofs was imported into VS. I can't seem to open the form for visual editing in VS.

Comment: I have since redesigned the form in VS and am accepting this as the answer.